# How to use commas in a string passed to a call function

Tags: makefile

### Background

I want to be able to specify Makefile options with a function so my help target can automatically list all defined options.

### What I've tried

Writing a function that stores the help text in a variable (and keeps track of a list of such variables), ready to be printed out later.

This works fine except when I use commas in my help strings!

I've tried debugging the failure and have reduced it to the following example that I think is the root cause:

I have the following makefile:

```
get_first_param = $(1)

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo $(call get_first_param, "Hi; my name is Peter")
```

If I run `make help`, this works fine and prints the message.

However, if I change the `;` to a `,` I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'help' failed
make: *** [help] Error 2
```

I assume this is because the call function treats the comma as marking the end of the first parameter and is so the return value is `"hi`.

(I am using Gnu Make 4.1)

### Question

Is there a way of using commas in the string successfully?

I've tried various ways of escaping the quotes and commas but nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to hide it behind a variable, like this:

```
C := ,

get_first_param = $(1)

.PHONY: help
help:
        @echo $(call get_first_param, "Hi$C my name is Peter")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you do:

```
get_first_param = $(1)
comma =,

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo $(call get_first_param, "Hi$(comma) my name is Peter")
```

but I don't know if this is the best way